# when button is clicked map doesn't work getting (NullPointerException)

Tags: android, google-maps

i have created button in a class lead to map in another class but when i clicked this button it crashes and get error(NullPointerException), i want to display this map when button is clicked and this is my code

```
    package com.example.gmapsapp;

import java.util.Stack;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

public class Airports extends FragmentActivity {
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.airports);
        createMapView();
        TSPNearestNeighbour TSP = new TSPNearestNeighbour();
        int[] shortest = new int[21];
        String[] placeNames = {"Cairo International Airport","Alexandria International Airport","Borg El Arab Airport",
                "Marsa Matrouh Airport","Sharm el-Sheikh International Airport","Taba International Airport","El Kharga Airport",
                "Assiut Airport","Luxor International Airport","Aswan International Airport","El Arish International Airport",
                "St. Catherine International Airport","Sharq Al-Owainat Airport","Abu Simbel Airport","Sohag International Airport",
                "Port Said Airport","El Tor Airport","Dakhla Oasis Airport","Marsa Alam International Airport","Cairo West Air Base","Almaza Air Force Base"};
        String[] placeNamesSnippet = {"Cairo International Airport1","Alexandria International Airport2","Borg El Arab Airport3", "Marsa Matrouh Airport4","Sharm el-Sheikh International Airport5","Taba International Airport6","El Kharga Airport7", "Assiut Airport8","Luxor International Airport9","Aswan International Airport10","El Arish International Airport11", "St. Catherine International Airport12","Sharq Al-Owainat Airport13","Abu Simbel Airport14","Sohag International Airport15", "Port Said Airport16","El Tor Airport17","Dakhla Oasis Airport18","Marsa Alam International Airpor19t","Cairo West Air Bas20e","Almaza Air Force Base21"};
        Double[] placeLatitude =  {30.111370, 31.192553, 30.917138,31.324435,27.978620,29.590988,27.188222,27.047695, 25.670264,
                23.960397,31.076449,28.684537,22.580600,22.375813,26.331926,31.281150,28.208842,25.688581,25.558141,
                30.116704,30.095975};
        Double[] placeLongitude = {31.413910, 29.953141,29.693375, 27.222200,34.393354,34.778946 , 33.800840, 31.013473 , 32.704063,
                32.821163,33.832256,34.062882, 28.720754, 31.611667,31.728437,32.242223,33.645257,28.972356,34.582821,
                30.916667,31.362748};

        Double[][] Matrix  = new Double[21][21];

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(placeLatitude[0], placeLongitude[0]), 13));
        for(int i = 0 ; i<21;i++)
        {
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .snippet(placeNamesSnippet[i])
                    .position(new LatLng(placeLatitude[i], placeLongitude[i]))
                    .title(placeNames[i]));
        }

        for(int i=0;i<21;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<21;j++)
            {
                Matrix[i][j] = distance(placeLatitude[i],placeLongitude[i],placeLatitude[j],placeLongitude[j],'K');
            }
        }

        shortest = TSP.tsp(Matrix);


        for(int i=0; i < 20 ; i++)
        {

            googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true)
                            .add(new LatLng(placeLatitude[shortest[i]],placeLongitude[shortest[i]]))
                            .add(new LatLng(placeLatitude[shortest[i+1]],placeLongitude[shortest[i+1]]))
            );
        }
    }

    private void createMapView(){
        /**
         */
        try {
            if(null == googleMap){
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.mapView)).getMap();
                /**
                 * If the map is still null after attempted initialisation,
                 * show an error to the user
                 */
                if(null == googleMap) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error creating map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException exception){
            Log.e("mapApp", exception.toString());
        }
    }
    private double rad2deg(double rad) {
        return (rad * 180 / Math.PI);
    }
    private double deg2rad(double deg) {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }
    private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, char unit)
    {
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        if (unit == 'K') {
            dist = dist * 1.609344;
        } else if (unit == 'N') {
            dist = dist * 0.8684;
        }
        return (dist);
    }
    public class TSPNearestNeighbour
    {
        private int numberOfNodes;
        private Stack<Integer> stack;

        public TSPNearestNeighbour()
        {
            stack = new Stack<Integer>();
        }

        public int[] tsp(Double adjacencyMatrix[][])
        {
            numberOfNodes = adjacencyMatrix[0].length ;
            int[] result = new int[adjacencyMatrix[0].length];
            int resultCounter = 1;
            int[] visited = new int[numberOfNodes];
            visited[0] = 1;
            stack.push(0);
            int element, dst = 0, i;
            Double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            boolean minFlag = false;
            result[0] = 0;

            //System.out.print(1 + "\t");

            while (!stack.isEmpty())
            {
                element = stack.peek();
                i = 0;
                min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                while (i < numberOfNodes)
                {
                    if (adjacencyMatrix[element][i] > 1 && visited[i] == 0)
                    {
                        if (min > adjacencyMatrix[element][i])
                        {
                            min = adjacencyMatrix[element][i];
                            dst = i;
                            minFlag = true;
                        }
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if (minFlag)
                {
                    visited[dst] = 1;
                    stack.push(dst);
                    result[resultCounter] = dst;
                    resultCounter++;
                    //System.out.print(dst + "\t");
                    minFlag = false;
                    continue;
                }
                stack.pop();
            }
            return result;
        }

    }

}
```

class which have the buttons

```
package com.example.gmapsapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class homepage extends MainActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout1);


}
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void onClick1(View view)
    {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, Airports.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

and the logcat is

```
 03-28 16:19:48.819: E/mapApp(4133): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133): Process: com.example.gmapsapp, PID: 4133
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gmapsapp/com.example.gmapsapp.Airports}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at com.example.gmapsapp.Airports.onCreate(Airports.java:42)
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-28 16:19:48.829: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     ... 11 more
```

sorry for bad english

Comment: Can you upload the code of starting activity where is onClick defined? You most likely failed to properly implement the onClick method.

Comment: you wrote "i have created button in a class lead to map in another class but when i clicked this button it crashes" Where is the class that defines what happens when you click the button that leads to the map? The error occurs probably there.

Comment: ok i will add this class

Answer (score 1):

You didnt initialize correctly the googleMap Object. Try initializing it before line 41. If you see you are initializing other GoogleMap object in createMapView  instead using the one that is used later in the oncreate Method.So your googleMap object will always be the null.

You should use this:

```
 googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.mapView)).getMap();
```

Comment: I've misread you answer, please edit it with the exact explanation what happened and it will be fine

Comment: Thanks nikis for understanding it.

Comment: jpcrow: yes still null

Comment: Are u sure that the id is R.id.mapView?

Comment: yes i copied the code exactly and the logcat is edited i will edit the code

Answer (score 0):

Try chaning this:

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void onClick1(View view)
{
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, Airports.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

to this:

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
  Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class
   startActivity(intent);
}
public void onClick1(View view)
{
  Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Airports.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```